# Unable to Delete or Unregister Dynamics365 plugin via the API

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to automate Plugin registrations on an instance of Dynamics 365 by using a powershell script which would make a call to the Dynamics API to unregister (or delete, either will do).

This is what my Powershell script looks like

```
param (
    [string] $PluginAssemblyId,  # The GUID of the plugin assembly to delete
    [string] $token              # The OAuth 2.0 access token for authentication
)

# Define the API endpoint for deleting the plugin assembly
$apiUrl = "https://<YourCRMInstance>/api/data/v<APIVersion>/pluginassemblies($PluginAssemblyId)"

# Define headers with the authorization token
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Send a DELETE request to remove the plugin assembly
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $headers -Method Delete

# Output the response
$response
```

But the response I am getting is 405 Method not allowed.

According to Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/reference/entities/pluginassembly), I should be able to do this, especially since I am able to register an assembly via an API call.